# Space between output elements

Tags: xslt

max xslt creates these following two elements:

**Target Snippet**

```
 <SalesManagement></SalesManagement>
   <locationOfSalesManagement>Hamburg</locationOfSalesManagement>
```

There is a blank line between these two in the Xslt, Hw can I forcte to create a blank line a written in the xslt? no line break within the value but the elements itself

T Thank you so much

**XSLT**

```
<SalesManagement>
        
            <xsl:value-of select="/JhMasterData/CoreBusiness/Sales/name"/>
    </SalesManagement>
    
    
    
        <locationOfSalesManagement>
            <xsl:value-of select="/JhMasterData/CoreBusiness/Sales/name/@loc"/>
        </locationOfSalesManagement>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context.